# Implementing security on ELK using x-pack

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to secure all the communications in ELK. For that i have installed x-pack plugin. Please let me know if its right plugin to do so.  I want to introduce username & password and also SSL enabled communication.

1. I have installed x-pack plugin in elasticsearch.
   **elasticsearch-plugin.bat install x-pack**
2. i have also learnt that there are 3 default  users in x-pack. **elastic**, **kibana** and **logstash-system**.
3. Even though i have installed x-pack only on elasticsearch, kibana also asks for credentials.

**My Doubts:**

1. I want to know why kibana is asking for credentials.
2. If i give credentials as **kibana/changeme**, i dont get any logs in kibana. But if i login as **elastic/changeme**, i can see logs in kibana.Why it is so? Is it like, the credentials used should be same across elasticsearch and kibana?
3. How should i manage using **elastic**, **kibana** and **logstash-system** users provided by x-pack?

Comment: now i have installed x-pack on kibana also along with Elasticsearch.I still see  only **elastic/changeme** works. In kibana.yml i used **elasticusername** as **elastic** and **elasticpassword** as  **changeme**.  i logged into kibana and elasticsearch using **elastic** and **changeme**. In **logstash.config file'e output section** also i have used username as **elastic** and password as **changeme**. Anywhere if i use **kibana/changeme** doesnt work.

Comment: Please let me know if i am on right track

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the users (assuming you are accessing Kibana on localhost and authenticate with `elastic` and `changeme`) at http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/management/security/users?_g=().

In that list you'll also see the user `kibana` with the role `kibana_system`. If you check out the details of that role, you'll see that it only has the `monitor` privilege and can only access the indices `.kibana*` and `.reporting-*`. That explains why your `kibana` user cannot see any data.

If you want to make this production ready:

- Only enable the users that you need.
- Change passwords.
- Maybe disable the default users and just create your own.

PS: I've only checked this on the 6.0.0-alpha2, but I think this should be the same on version 5 as well.

Comment: Thanks... Now i am trying to add certifcates in order to get the secure communication. First i am trying between elasticsearch and logstash, in **elasticsearch.yml** below are the changes i have done

Comment: **network.host:** 132.186.102.39
**xpack.security.enabled:** true
**xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled:** true
**xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled:** true
**xpack.ssl.key:** "D:/Softwares/ELK/elasticsearch-5.4.0/elasticsearch-5.4.0/config/x-pack/ELK_SSL_Certificates/server/pkcs8.key"
**xpack.ssl.certificate:** "D:/Softwares/ELK/elasticsearch-5.4.0/elasticsearch-5.4.0/config/x-pack/ELK_SSL_Certificates/server/cert.pem"
**xpack.ssl.certificate_authorities:** "D:/Softwares/ELK/elasticsearch-5.4.0/elasticsearch-5.4.0/config/x-pack/ELK_SSL_Certificates/testca/cacert.pem"

Comment: logstash.conf changes,   output {
    elasticsearch {
 hosts => ["132.186.102.39:9200"]
 user => "elastic"
 password => "changeme"
 ssl => true
 cacert => "D:/Softwares/ELK/elasticsearch-5.4.0/elasticsearch-5.4.0/config/x-pack/ELK_SSL_Certificates/testca/cacert.pem"
 #cacert => "D:/Softwares/ELK/elasticsearch-5.4.0/elasticsearch-5.4.0/config/x-pack/certificate-bundle/ca/ca.crt"
 #xpack.ssl.certificate_authorities => ["D://Softwares//ELK//ELK_SSL_Certificates//testca//cacert.pem"]
 }
 stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}

Comment: After i make these changes, i am getting following error,   **logstash.outputs.elasticsearch - Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>#<URI::HTTPS:0xce46638 URL:https://elastic:xxxxxx@132.186.102.39:9200/>, :error_type=>LogStash::O
utputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [https://elastic:xxxxxx@132.186.102.39:9200/][Manticore::ClientProtocolException] KeyUsage does not allow digital
 signatures"}**

Comment: elasticsearch is up on running.. Can you please help me in understanding the issue

Comment: if i add **ssl_certificate_verification => false** in logstash.conf , then i dont get error. i am using self signed certificates. is it ok to set this variable to false.

Comment: Please open another question, since this is a new topic.